# Favorite system recovery Live CD?

Tags: live-cd, system-restore

What's your system recovery CD? I've used Ultimate Boot CD and GParted. What works for you?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Trinity Rescue Kit](http://trinityhome.org/Home/index.php?content=TRINITY_RESCUE_KIT_DOWNLOAD&front_id=12&lang=en&locale=en) (version 3.4)

> It is possible to boot TRK in three different ways:
>
> - as a bootable CD which you can burn yourself from a downloadable isofile or a self burning Windows executable
> - from a USB stick/disk (optionally also a fixed disk), installable from Windows or from the bootable TRK cd (which is easier and safer)
> - from network over PXE: you start 1 TRK from CD or USB and you run all other computers from that one over the network without modifying anything to you local network
>
> Here 's a sumup of some of the most important features, new and old:
>
> - easily reset windows passwords with the improved winpass tool
> - simple and easy menu interface
> - 5 different virusscan products integrated in a single uniform commandline with online update capability
> - full ntfs write support thanks to ntfs-3g
> - winclean, a utility that cleans up all sorts of unnecessary temporary files on your computer
> - clone computers over the network via multicast
> - wide range of hardware support (kernel 2.6.35)
> - contributed backup utility called "pi", to automate local machine backups
> - easy script to find and mount all local filesystems
> - self update capability to include and update all virusscanners + local changes you made to TRK
> - full proxyserver support
> - run a samba fileserver (windows like filesharing)
> - run a ssh server
> - recovery and undeletion of files with utilities and procedures
> - recovery of lost partitions
> - evacuation of dying disks
> - full read/write and rpm support
> - UTF-8 international character support (select keyboard language from the scrollable textmenu at startup)
> - 2 rootkit detection uitilities
> - most software updated to recent versions
> - literally thousands of changes and bugfixes since version 3.3
> - elaborated documentation, including manpages for all commands (also TRK 's own)

Comment: Add a space after -

Comment: Try stars so markdown will create an unordered list of it ^^

Answer (score 7):

grml as in grml.org! :) It's designed as a Live System for system administrators. It provides:

- > 2500 software packages
- 3 different flavours (grml, grml-medium, grml-small), all of them available as:
- 32bit and 64bit version
- LVM and software RAID support out of the box (including bootoptions for autoenabling them)
- support for booting via PXE/USB/...
- ssh-server through bootoption 'ssh=password'
- support for remote acces via iSCSI
- support for all the relevant filesystems (ext3/ext4, xfs, ntfs,...)
- tools and bootoptions for forensical and data rescue investigations
- default boot into console (X.org available through grml-x) providing a full featured GNU screen, htop, multitail,... setup
- a great Zsh default configuration

Disclaimer: yes, I'm related to grml. :)

Answer (score 2):

Besides Trinity, I also like [Backtrack](http://www.remote-exploit.org/backtrack.html)

Answer (score 2):

[Hiren's boot CD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd) works for recovery but it really shines when you need to repartion or format drives, check hardware errors and fix file systems.

Answer (score 1):

I've used http://www.ubcd4win.com/ before, not for a while though

Answer (score 1):

[Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) too. Found an hard drive error with it, although those apps are not the most intuitive thing on earth.

Answer (score 1):

System Rescue CD (sysrescd) due to inertia - did some customization, prepared some scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used knoppix, mostly due to inertia. But recently have had the need to run a decent virus scanner on non functional machines - I used the tools kaspersky provide to make Bart Pe boot disks and have found them very useful.

Answer (score 0):

ERD Emergency Rescue Disk...lets you boot into a windows-like environment, edit the registry, copy/delete files, browse the drives, etc.

I have also used Hirems and Backtrack, but I really like ERD.