# old dell 600sc with corrupt data

Tags: windows-server-2003

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Crashed Hard Drive Data Retrieval](https://serverfault.com/questions/4331/crashed-hard-drive-data-retrieval)

I need data from a dell sc600 running 2003 server for an upgrade to 2008 r2.Old dell is so corrupt,backup is full of errors,so copying any files across network is unreliable.Ideas for getting data,including user files onto new machine?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Quite simply, remove the drive, put it in a system that you know works (the PIV is old, and may be capacitor plague era - lets reduce variables), check the drive health with a suitable tool (smartmontools, or a drive specific maintenance tool) and run [ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html) to get as much data out as possible. I'd also recommend finding the most recent known good backups (you *do* have that don't you?) to try to fill in anything ddrescue can't find.

Comment: Nothing more to add.

Comment: Thanks,checking ddrescue,last known good bup in 2009.Tried fbackup to new nas,incomplete resuls.machine keeps dropping and resetting admin pword,user files for AD would be good result.

Comment: Why not try backing it up to a USB drive instead of continuing to struggle with backing it up to a network location?

Comment: the old one is usb 1.0,tried copying onto WD usb drive,just took forever.NAS is gigbit ethernet,but old dell drops processes so badly,two mins. is most I've gotten.Think I ve found a stable 2003 server,now have to match iscsi and copy two  drives,about 50 gig of data,I had the same usb thought,even took a large capacity one to do,then saw speed,and process drops.Just nursing along to new server dcpromote.Thanks for the thought.